# Google pie chart data table values

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

In Google website the code for creating a pie chart is:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

I have a global var that I would like to set it's value and insert the new value to the chart, for instance:

```
    var tmp=MyGlobalVariable+10;
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     tmp],
      ['Eat',      3],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);
```

Every time I use the tmp var it eliminates the 'work' from the chart.
How can I dynamically set the data table values?

Answer (score 0):

The google chart library renders an SVG from a dataset.

If you want to change the svg, you will have to 'redraw (drawChart())' the chart.

a small example (untested, and proably buggy due to not a lot of time):

```
window.myChart = {
    data : [
        ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
        ['Work', 11],
        ['Eat', 2],
        ['Commute', 2],
        ['Watch TV', 2],
        ['Sleep', 7]
    ],
    options : {
        title: 'My Daily Activities'
    },
    chart : null,
    init : function(elId) {
        this.chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(elId));
        this.drawChart();
    },
    drawChart : function()
    {
        this.chart.draw(this.data, this.options);
    }
};
```

usage:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
myChart.init('my-chart-id')
google.setOnLoadCallback(myChart.drawChart);
```

Then everytim you want to change some data:

```
mychart.data['work'] = 10;
mychart.drawChart();
```

Comment: Pinoniq - Can you write some code lines explaining how to redraw the chart with new values?

Comment: small code example added. this probably doesn't fit into your application 'as is'. You could also implement a onchange event thingy so that when you change the data, the cart is automatically redrawn